# ld: warning: method '-persistentCacheIndexManager' in category

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I just installed "CloudFirestore" with "Swift Package Manager" in my xcode project.

Firebase SDK Version 10.0.0

Xcode Version 14.3.1

Installation Method Swift Package Manager

I waited for xCode to finish indexing all the files.

And this warning appeared, how can I solve the problem?

ld: warning: method '-persistentCacheIndexManager' in category from /Users/--/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testFirebaseCloudFirestore-Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework/FirebaseFirestoreInternal(FIRFirestore.o) overrides method from class in /Users/--/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testFirebaseCloudFirestore-Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework/FirebaseFirestoreInternal(FIRFirestore.o)